# May I sell digital content (e.g. photos, PDFs and videos) using Facebook Payments?

Tags: facebook

Is one permitted to sell digital goods using Facebook Payments?

Looking at https://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/ I understand:

- I **am not** permitted to sell tangible goods (any good that is physically delivered) using Facebook Payments.
- I **am** permitted to sell in-game digital goods such as weapons.
  For example, if I were a photographer, could I create a Facebook app that showed low-resolution versions of photos but then use Facebook Payments to sell downloads of the high-resolution versions of those photos from within the app?

Comment: Why don't you ask Facebook?

Comment: @ChrisF - don't suppose you know how to contact Facebook?  https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=176791949076747&ref_query=contact+ says there's a custom form but I cannot find it anywhere!

Comment: Have you checked the links on this page - https://www.facebook.com/help/ads-and-business-solutions

Answer (score 2):

Hat tip to Gajus Kuizinas who has clarified this for me.

> You may not utilize Facebook Payments to sell virtual currency or
>   other stored-value item that can be used outside of the app where the
>   transaction was completed.

In short, no: Facebook Payments cannot be used for digital downloads.

Comment: what app? The Facebook app?